# REST API url parameters "+" as blank

Tags: api, rest, url, parameters

I have the uri "/job/killJobs?jobId=**tg+h1qjGGJbpwVAw9C1Pvw**"
where tg+h1qjGGJbpwVAw9C1Pvw is the job Id,

Comment: But when I am fetching the value I am getting **[tg h1qjGGJbpwVAw9C1Pvw]**    
Getting blank space at "+" sign how to get the parameter value as it is ?

Answer (score 0):

> Getting blank space at "+"

What's happening is that your "fetching the value" code is applying an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` decoding of the query part, but you haven't used the matching *encoding* procedure when creating the URI.

```
/job/killJobs?jobId=tg%2Bh1qjGGJbpwVAw9C1Pvw
```

should produce the result you want (%2B being the pct-encoding of `+`).